# Debian Lenny renders fonts awful (like a ransom note) with default Desktop install

Tags: fonts, debian-lenny

I'm running up-to-date Debian Lenny for x86-64. I am using the iceweasel browser.

I browse to the web page crypto.org/blog and see the following:

[image: Badly rendered fonts]

<sup>Click for larger image</sup>

It looks like a ransom note! tHe texT iS VarYinG iN SiZe (except that the letters are all lower case, differing in size by about a point and a half).

It renders fine on all other browsers. (See [for yourself](http://www.crypto.com/blog/law_school_exam/).)

Please don't suggest installing the Microsoft fonts. I am looking to fix the problem rendering the existing fonts (that doesn't occur on other Debian-derived distros), not add new ones.

Comment: Please clarify whether the text varies in *size* (i.e. all lowercase letters, but letter height varies by some pixels), like you state in your question, or the text alters uppercase and lowercase, like you show in the example. Also, did you try to view the same page in another browser so you can be sure there's no defacing going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all TrueType fonts are Microsoft fonts. The only Microsoft font package is `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

I suggest installing *other* TrueType fonts.

This will install all of them, except `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (note the `grep -v mscorefonts`):

```
apt-cache search ttf | awk '/^ttf/ {print $1}' | grep -v mscorefonts | xargs apt-get install
```

Those other Debian derived distros (like Ubuntu) install all of the fonts by default. Debian doesn't. That's the difference.

Comment: This is not the only site that looks wrong.  I want to make them all work.  Supplying an additional font does not make that font the "default alternative" for the font this site specifies.  If I install more fonts, I need to install fonts that will fix this.  What font IS the browser picking for this site?  (How do I tell?)  Is that font actually ugly, or is there a rendering bug?  Why would I have that bug in a default (Desktop role) Debian install?

Comment: If you want to be conservative with some not very ugly fonts just install `ttf-bitstream-vera`.

Answer (score 0):

Iceweasel menu : Edit > Preferences > Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced > uncheck Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above.